# Can't get form to display mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, exact-match

I'm fairly new to MySQL and PHP and have been reading books and watching tutorials and trying examples but I'm stuck on getting this search query to work.
I have a simple search form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 5</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
 <form name="search" method="post" action="process_search.php">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"/>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is the part of the php form that processes the search request that I'm having issues with

```
$db_path ="localhost"; //---Host name or path to database
$db_username ="root"; //-----------------------------MySQL database username
$db_password = "password"; //----------------------------MySQL database password
$db_name = "database"; //--------------------------------MySQL database name
$tbl_name = "stuff"; //---------------------------------MySQL database table

// Connect to server and select databse
 mysql_connect("$db_path", "$db_username", "$db_password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//filtering input for xss and sql injection
$input = @$_GET['find'];
$input = strip_tags( $input );
$input = mysql_real_escape_string( $input );
$input = trim( $input );





$sql = mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name WHERE first_name = '". $input . "'");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

I'm following the example given but the query doesn't return any results, it will display the table headers as it should but nothing in the tables, I added mysql_error(); to my code and it reports no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna change your query to...

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from $tbl_name WHERE first_name LIKE '%". $input . "%'");
```

But you really shouldn't be using mysql_*, its deprecated, you should use PDO to connect to the database

EDIT...

Your form has a method of **"post"**
so you should have this instead...

```
$input = $_POST['find'];
```

I believe that will solve your problem! :)

EDIT 2...

Ok you need to find out why your form isnt posting the variable...
So just have this on the page...

```
 <form name="search" method="post" action="process_search.php">
  Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"/>
 </form>
```

and on your php page have nothing but...

```
<?php var_dump($_REQUEST);?>
```

Tell me what you get....
I would chat with you but you don't have enough rep points to chat, so hence multiple edits.

Comment: I want an exact return of the query so that's why I used = not like

Comment: the example is the book shows to use @$_get['find']; when I remove the @ I get an undefined index find error

Comment: does the query process the keyword input from the name of the input box in the search form? so my input box is named "find"

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives me the undefined index find error

Comment: what happens if you comment everything out of process_search.php, and just echo $_POST['find'], does it echo to the screen the value you typed into the box?  no @, just $_POST['find']

Answer (score 0):

Use this - I believe this works. If you still have no results, you may have another problem.

```
$db_path ="localhost"; //---Host name or path to database
$db_username ="root";  //-----------------------------MySQL database username
$db_password = "password"; //----------------------------MySQL database password
$db_name = "database"; //--------------------------------MySQL database name

// Connect to server and select databse
 mysql_connect("$db_path", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//filtering input for xss and sql injection
$input = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_REQUEST['find'])));

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE first_name='$input'");

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Comment: I want the search to return the exact keyword search so if they enter 1234 I only want the return for 1234. Doesn't LIKE and % give a return result of variations of the query?

Comment: hes not even getting the post variable from the form...this goes deeper

Comment: well obviously.....if your variable isn't even making it to the second page, you wont have results...you need to find out why the form isn't posting the variable...this is less of a database issue, then it is a PHP issue

Comment: @KyleK if I remove everything from the process_search.php page and just put the $_POST['find'] should it display the value entered in the box?

Comment: yes, it should, thats what I wanted you to try.....I also have a new suggestion in my edited post above...try that

Comment: shouldn't it be echo $_POST['find']; ? and I changed it from get to post and that just makes the undefined index: find error go away but still doesn't post results.

Comment: $_REQUEST will get $_GET and $_POST and $_COOKIE....you are right though, it should be $_POST['find']....$_REQUEST is considered bad practice

Comment: Have you tried just var_dump($_POST)...and nothing else on your php page?  what did you get?

Comment: I figured it out, it was a problem with the html of the button instead action I had value so it was posting the value of search instead of the name of the input. Thank you both for your assistance. Kyle once I just made a blank process_search.php page and tried it I saw that it was posting the value of search which is what the button value was.